# Combining/Resolving Two Repository Types in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

In my Gradle project, I need to define two types of repositories: a flat directory and a Maven repository (a local Nexus server).

I can get both working separately, but can't get them to play nicely together. Ideally, I would have Gradle look at the local directory first, then at the Maven repository.

**Current Setup**

I have defined the repositories in my `build.gradle` like this:

```
repositories {
    flatDir dirs: "${rootProject.projectDir}/libs"  
    flatDir dirs: "${rootProject.projectDir}/test.libs"

    maven {
        credentials {
            username nexus_username
            password nexus_password
        }
        url "http://nexus-server/nexus/content/groups/public"
    }
}
```

In the `libs` (and `test.libs`) directory, the jar file names may or may not have versioning (but when using a `flatDir` repository, I believe that is irrelevant):

```
libs\activation.jar
libs\imap.jar
....
libs\<closed_source_framework>.jar
....
libs\gson-2.2.4.jar
libs\stax-utils.jar
.....
```

The reason I can't use our local Nexus server for everything is because of `<closed_source_framework>.jar`; most of the dependancies in the `libs` folder come packaged with that distribution, and I can't reliably get the version information to pull them from Nexus.

Now, one of the other teams is publishing their jars to the Nexus server and I'd like to be able to pull their jars from Nexus, so I have (re)defined my dependencies in my `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {

    // Grab other-team jar files from Nexus server
    compile "other-team-group:other-team-jar-1:version"
    compile "other-team-group:other-team-jar-2:version"
    compile "other-team-group:other-team-jar-3:version"

    // Grab everything else from 'flatDir'
    compile name: 'activation'
    compile name: 'imap'
    ...
    compile name: 'gson-2.2.4'
    compile name: 'stax-utils'
    .....

}
```

**The Problem**

So now comes my problem. I had expected Gradle would search the `repositories` in the order specified in my `build.gradle`; meaning that it would look to the local `libs` folder first and then go to Nexus if it can't find it locally. What I'm seeing instead is that Gradle is looking at the Nexus server for the jar files already in the local `libs` folder. Obviously, this is slowing down my build (I have ~30 dependencies defined).

**Some Info**

Output from `gradle properties` command, to show repository information:

```
.....
repositories: [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultFlatDirArtifactRepository_Decorated@18814b1b, org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository_Decorated@6dff028]
.....
```

Output from `gradle --info compileJava`, to show that Gradle is doing a lookup to Nexus:

```
.....
// Successfully find the other team jar files in Nexus, this is okay
Download http://nexus-server/nexus/content/groups/public/other-team-group/other-team-jar-1/version/other-team-jar-1-version.pom
Download http://nexus-server/nexus/content/groups/public/other-team-group/other-team-jar-2/version/other-team-jar-2-version.pom
Download http://nexus-server/nexus/content/groups/public/other-team-group/other-team-jar-3/version/other-team-jar-3-version.pom
.....
// Continues looking in Nexus for jar files that should be found in local libs folder
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://nexus-server/nexus/content/groups/public//activation//activation-.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://nexus-server/nexus/content/groups/public//activation//activation-.jar]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://nexus-server/nexus/content/groups/public///imap//imap-.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://nexus-server/nexus/content/groups/public//imap//imap-.jar]
.....
```

**Bottom Line**

How can I get Gradle to stop looking at the Maven repository for jar files that I know it will only find locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also posted this question over on the [Gradle forums](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/combining-resolving-two-repository-types-in-gradle/18344/2?u=wildempsey). I have copy/pasted the solution below.

---

> Gradle will prefer an artifact with an pom/ivy descriptor over an
>   artifact without. I think this is why gradle continues searching after
>   it finds a match in the flatDir repository. This may or may not solve
>   your problem, but you could use a [FileCollectionDependency](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/FileCollectionDependency.html) instead of
>   a [ModuleDependency](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ModuleDependency.html).
>
> Eg:

```
ext {
   libs = "${rootProject.projectDir}/libs"
   testLibs = "${rootProject.projectDir}/test.libs"
}
dependencies {
   compile files("${libs}/activation.jar", "${libs}/imap.jar")
   compile files("${testLibs}/gson-2.2.4.jar")
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe (as shown in [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html)) using:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {dirs "${rootProject.projectDir}/libs","${rootProject.projectDir}/test.libs"}
}
```

It works for me